# red dot in chrome debugger when writing LESS?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, less, google-chrome-devtools

I'm transforming my css files into LESS file.

only part of my LESS is working well and I see a weird red dot line in the chrome debugger for those problematic lines,

any idea what they means?

[image]

Comment: show some of the mark up of your less file

Answer (score 3):

http://codemirror.net/doc/releases.html says that Version 2.33 of CodeMirror introduced "Show non-printing characters as red dots."

Comment: what is CodeMirror and how to I use it in vs2012?