# Stylesheets not working in nginx virtual machine

Tags: html, css, nginx

i'm desperate. My stylesheets are just not working. I don't get it. When i try to debug them in Chrome I get this:

[image: Red dots of doom]

I've never encountered this problem before. It's driving me crazy. I'm simply adding them in the `<head>` section of the html page: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/cry-with-me.css">`

What should those awful red dots of doom mean? My css is fine, because when i update the style live, it works. And also every time i add a new stylesheet, the website does use the styles. But the moment i update them or do the slightest modification to the original file, this red dots appear. Maybe it has to do something with browser caching, but I tried using incognito mode, opening other browsers, everything.

Perhaps the solution is pretty straightforward, but i can't for the live of me make it work. Or does it have to do with my nginx server setup? mmmm....

Comment: try adding type="text/css" attribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267505/red-dot-in-chrome-debugger-when-writing-less :)

Comment: Hi, @hirish I tried that. Same result =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured it out (well, found a [link on the internets](http://jeremyfelt.com/code/2013/01/08/clear-nginx-cache-in-vagrant) to go about it) and though i should just put it here in case anyone runs into this. It turns out `sendfile` (which is used to *copy data between one file descriptor and another* gets really messed up when running on a virtual machine (Virtualbox on Vagrant, in my case). So you just have to go into the nginx.conf file and set `sendfile` to `off`. And don't forget to restart nginx after that.

Here is the article that helped me sort this out:
http://jeremyfelt.com/code/2013/01/08/clear-nginx-cache-in-vagrant/#comment-1846